# Jquery date picker not firing on focus of text field

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a website that I'm working on: http://parishes.rcda.org:81/christtheking/ECC.php

If I click the link to schedule a visit (lower left side of the white area in the middle of the page), a form opens in a modal window.

If I click on the text box for "When would you like to come for your tour?", the date picker does not load.

I've checked the developer tool in Firefox and found an error telling me that:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function                  @http://parishes.rcda.org:81/christtheking/ECC.php#popup3:745:29
l@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29373
a/</c<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677
undefined jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:30920
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function[Learn More] ECC.php:745:29
<anonymous>
http://parishes.rcda.org:81/christtheking/ECC.php:745:29
l
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29373
a/</c<
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677
```

I'm not sure if this is due to the fact that the site uses bootstrap and jquery and that I have the correct versions.

I did check that I had the correct field name in the datepicker calling script.

```
$(function () {
        $("#visitDate").datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: did you load jquery UI?

Comment: jquery library is loaded twice in your document. Correct this first...

Comment: I've checked my code and removed one set of Jquery load statements. I now only have:  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> 
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The template was purchased from theme forest and one of the asset .js files caused the date picker not to function. I removed it and it now works.

I opened the file in the browser and found out that the file is  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 and since I had 2 libraries on the page, no go.

Answer (score 0):

Remove one instance of jquery loading on your page and `datepicker()` will work.

Post back if it doesn't work for you.

Here is an example I set up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/uo87xbj4/

You need:

- JQuery Js
- JQuery UI Js
- JQuery UI CSS (this is if you want the styling to go with the datepicker)

Comment: I removed one instance of jquery loading and now get $ is not defined. I then found the other set of jquery and removed it. The first set: jquery-3.3.1.min.js & 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js caused $ is not defined errors. The other set i found was: jquery-1.12.4.js & 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js. removing them caused: jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function & $(...).datepicker is not a function.

Comment: I read here on SO that someone else had this issue due to the order of the scripts on my page. That could be my problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uo87xbj4/ - You also need to include jquery UI Js and CSS... for it to work correctly

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle and know that is what I want. but can't get it to work. I've switched to the google hosted CDN for JQuery and am still getting the error  $(...).datepicker is not a function. I also verified that I have only one set of scripts on the site. why is this so difficult?

Comment: Can you post your section in simplified format here?

Comment: I am seeing a different error now on your page: `google-analytics.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: The error with the google-analytics.js file is being thrown by the code that google analytics gave me on their site. The line tossing the error is: <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-#######"></script> removing the script from the page does not affect the date picker.

Comment: Can you post your section in simplified format here?  -- What section do you want?

Comment: A simplified version of the page you are generating... get rid anything that is not necessary to see what the issue can be,.

Comment: http://parishes.rcda.org:81/u.php  I've simplified the code with just the form and it functions as expected. maybe there is something in one of my .js files that is causing an error. I don't know but it's not my Jquery files or the form.

Comment: and it works... as expected! I have a feeling something in your code that is causing the issue...

Comment: What I would recommend is... with your new page, build upon that since the date textbox is already working.